# play youtube video in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to put video inside div and in you click on play button this video will open in modal video in the center of the screen. This is example http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Youtube-Video-Modal-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-3-YTModal/ how this should work.

I have following html code:

```
<div class="news-bar-content">
    <div class="news-bar-items">
    here should be video from youtube
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ytmodel helps you to play youtube vidoe in a pop up center of page , 
to do this . you will have to embed bootstrap 3  , jquery , javascript in header .
`=

`Load the jQuery YouTubeDefaultImageLoader.js plugin's JavaScript and CSS files in the document.`

`
Embed an Youtube video into your document as follow. You can use the DIV's ID attribute to specify the ID of Youtube video you want to embed.

```
<div id="y73mJZdMEcw"class="youtubeVideoLoader"></div>
```

now whenever someone clicks on the div class='youtubevideoloader, a video window will appear on screen like u want .